# Android : Can't put a string through an intent from a fragment to an activity

Tags: android

I'm new in android development and I have an issue with simple string in an intent.
I create an Intent in a fragment to launch a new activity. I have no error but I can't put a string through the intent.
Here is my code :

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

     private static Context mContext;
```

I have this in the onCreateView method :

```
     mContext = this.getContext();
```

This method in the same class

```
public static void openModalPolicy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ModalActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("section", "policy");
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in my new activity :

```
        String section = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("section");
```

So the problem is that section is never equal to "policy"
If someone can help me :) Have a good day !

Comment: `the problem is that section is never equal to "policy"` what is it's value then? or how do u check for it's value?

Comment: Show the whole function and classes where each piece of code was taken from.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using `section.equals("policy")` for your equality check. Not `section == "policy"`. Right?

Comment: I forgot that we have to use .equal() in java. I'm an idiot thank you ^^

Comment: @LoïcCombis don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure, you are using `section.equals("policy")` for your equality check.
Not `section == "policy"`. Right?

Check out this post for more information: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)